# Express js req.body returns empty

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I've tried the all solutions from some another stackoverflow posts but it didn't solved my issue.

Here is my `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var index = require('./routes/index');
var v1    = require('./routes/route');

app.use('/', index);
//routes for api
app.use('/v1',v1);
```

Here is my `post` controller

```
module.exports = {

    createUser:function (req,res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send('ok'+req.body.test);
    }
}
```

`req.body` returns `{}` even if the request body contains the parameters.

I am checking the api's with postman plugin.

**Update**

Postman request

[image]

Comment: can you post your Postman Request?

Comment: on what route you use the post controller?

Comment: Let me update my question

Comment: You need to send json, not form-data

Comment: And then you'll also need to set your Content-Type header: `{"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}`

Comment: There is no option in postman to send data as json

Comment: select the `x-www-form-urlencoded` in postman and set `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: It IS an option, you can send `raw`, and set the proper JSON header

Comment: Yes, there is, you need to select "raw" and select "application/json"

Comment: Just added `{
test:"hello"
}` in  `raw` area but again req.body is undefined

Comment: @p0k8_ your answer worked fine

Comment: in raw options did you select type `JSON(application/json)`

Comment: @Jabaa did you add the Content-Type header?

Comment: @Creynders i selected the `json`  from  `raw` now i got an error  `Unexpected token e in JSON at position 4`

Comment: Ah, it's not real JSON, it should be `{"test":"hello"}`

Comment: Got it it works but which one is better www-form-url-encoded or json??. api are requested from android/ios devices

Comment: `application/json` is used when you are posting the data `{"test":"hello"}` like this,

`www-form-url-encoded` is used to get the data as key-value in object from the url when used the `bodyParser.urlencoded`, 
They both are different and have their own use cases

Comment: For sensitive informations like password which one is best

Comment: @p0k8 post yr comments as an answer

Comment: @Jabaa Sure I will answer it beautifully, please wait for mine answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`body-parser`**](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser)

The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares. All middlewares will populate the `req.body` property with the parsed body, or an empty object `{}` if there was no body to parse (or an error was returned).

---

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for encoded bodies
```

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware, `req.body` will contain the parsed data, this object will contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array

The Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

---

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for json encoded bodies
```

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. `req.body`).

The Content-Type is `application/json`

---

`application/json` is used when you are posting the data `{"test":"hello"}` like this. `www-form-url-encoded` is used to get the data as key-value in object from the url when used the `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. They both are different and have their own use cases

Answer (score 3):

After removing the last 4 lines of code (to be sure you are configuring correctly the routes) and adding this test lines:

```
app.post('/ping', function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('ok ' + req.body.test);
});
let server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8899, function onstart() {
    console.log('server listening');
});
```

When I run:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8899/ping -d '{"test": 1234}'
```

I get `ok undefined`, like you did. After adding the proper `content-type` header:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8899/ping -d '{"test": 1234}' -H "content-type: application/json"
```

it works like a charm and I get `ok 1234`. So I think you are missing the `"content-type: application/json"` header in your postman.

Comment: I've been burned by that, more than once :(