# Why is request.body is empty?

Tags: node.js, ajax, angular, http, express

I have been building a simple blogging app using the Mean stack and I seem to struggle, the request.body is always empty even though I send data here's the code and the request is always pending in Chrome network tab till it gives Err_connction_refused or something like that and notice that I pass form data to the service which is where the problem lies

The Register service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
// A form data is passed as an argument to this function
      register(user) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/users/register", user, {headers})
        .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
    }
}
```

The routes in the server side-side (side-note: don't worry about the req.file.path)

```
// Registering a user
router.post("/register", upload.single("profileImage") , (req, res) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        interests: req.body.interests,
        profileImage: req.body.path
    })
    User.addUser(newUser, (err) => {
        if (err) return err;
        res.send({
            success: "true",
            msg: "You've logged in sucessfully"
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Comment: It seems that you do not use bodyParser at the back end. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227729/express-js-req-body-returns-empty for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st step `npm i body-parser`

after installing the module add the below code to your app.js

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

**Edit**

used URL is  **`http://localhost:3000/api/users/register`**

But Your Route is only `/register`.

your route and passed URL should match

Comment: And I heard that bodyparser doesn't process form data correct me if I'm wrong and notice that this is form data wgich includes text fields and an image

Comment: No I use express Router and it's not about the route

Comment: your http request should look like this : return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000//register", user, {headers})

Comment: After adding the bodyparser.urlencoded() and removing the         headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")

Comment: @OmarAli great.. Please accept my answer so it will help others also.

Comment: You got that dude